# Dataframe Transformation - Pandas

Tags: pandas, transform

I am trying to pick certain columns based on the outcome of the weekday column.

For example:

site1 for the day 2020-12-31(Tuesday) should pick values from mon_open and mon_close since it is a weekday.

site 10 for the day 2020-12-29(Sunday) should pick values from sun_open and sun_close since it is a sunday.

[image]

[image]

Any help with this highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to say "site 10 for the day 2020-12-29(Sunday) should pick values from sun_open and sun_close since it is `NOT` a weekday."?

Comment: Corrected. Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `np.where` like this:

```
df['open'] = np.where(df['weekday'].isin([5, 6]), df['sun_open'], df['mon_open'])
df['close'] = np.where(df['weekday'].isin([5, 6]), df['sun_close'], df['mon_close'])
```